# Key point working with container view controller (adding as subview/ remove from superview ) - generally we miss

Tags: uiviewcontroller

Implementing a Container View Controller

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: Useful but not a question.